# How can I set my class properties values Using Reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, uwp

Good Day,

Lets say this is my class:

```
public class MyClass {

    public bool boolProp { get; set; }
    public string stringProp { get; set; }
}
```

this is my IDictionary:

```
IDictionary<string, string> myDict= 
        new IDictionary<string, string>();

myDict.Add("boolProp", "true");
myDict.Add("stringProp", "teststring");
```

So I want to update my class properties using Reflection where my dictionary keys matches the name of property then set its value by creating a  method, how is that?

Method parameter should be like this:

```
public void UpdateProperties(IDictionary<string, string> myDict) {
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

With [GetProperty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kz0a8sxy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
IDictionary<string, string> myDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

myDict.Add("boolProp", "true");
myDict.Add("stringProp", "teststring");

var s = new MyClass();
var t = s.GetType();

foreach (var values in myDict)
{
    var p = t.GetProperty(values.Key, System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public);

    var c = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(p.PropertyType);
    var convertedValue = c.ConvertFromInvariantString(values.Value);

    p.SetValue(s, convertedValue);
}
```

Comment: Thanks , btw my method is inside MyClass , and iam getting String cannot be converted to Boolean , how to automatically convert that? what Iam passing is always string , cause its from the backend

Comment: @NicoTing changed answer with converter

Comment: TypeDescriptor does not exist , no namespace suggested , btw Im developing uwp app , already include using System.ComponentModel;

Comment: @NicoTing MSDN says, it exists https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt185499.aspx

Comment: @NicoTing sorry, I can't help with it

Comment: What're the target version and min version of your project? If the target and min version are both 16299, then, you do not need add any namespace. It's contained in .net standard 2.0. If the target and min version are previous version (e.g, 15063, 14393....etc), you would need to add `System.Reflection` namespace.